# How does one debug application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation?

Tags: ios

Apple's documentation about the new iOS smart banners feature in mobile Safari talks about how to implement `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` to allow your app to be opened from the banner, taking the user directly to a specific area of your app:

[Promoting Apps with Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH6-SW1)

My question is, how does one test/debug this functionality? I.e. how can you trigger a call to `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` passing in a test URL of your choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a custom url scheme like walmart://whatever/whatever you can type it into safari and it'll hit `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation`

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I think my confusion was in the example Apple gives on that site I linked, it seems to imply the URL coming in will be a regular http:// URL (in their case: http://example.com/profile/?12345). But now I see that I could technically pass any sort of URL into the smart banner meta tag, including a custom one with a url scheme like the one you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: it can be a regular url in the case of smart app banners in iOS6. so that is a bit of a hassle to test.

Comment: But am I right in saying that the smart banner meta tag COULD be specified with a "special" URL, like walmart://whatever, or is that URL supplied supposed to be a regular http:// URL? (Which will the re-raise my question as to how exactly to test that.)